# Should HBase Connection be kept alive?

Tags: hbase

I am using HBase 1.2, and I am reading/write HBase in a web application.

Following is the javadoc for the HBase Connection class

```
 * <p> Connection creation is a heavy-weight operation. Connection implementations are thread-safe,
 * so that the client can create a connection once, and share it with different threads.
 * {@link Table} and {@link Admin} instances, on the other hand, are light-weight and are not
 * thread-safe.  Typically, a single connection per client application is instantiated and every
 * thread will obtain its own Table instance. Caching or pooling of {@link Table} and {@link Admin}
 * is not recommended.
```

From the doc, The `Connection` object is thread safe, so that I could create a singleton connection among the application.

My question is:

If I haven't used this `Connection` object  to read/write HBase for a long time, will this Connection object be a dead object, that is , I have to ping HBase using this Connection periodically?

This is how long a connection can be idle issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all managed from within the `Connection` itself - if it's been inactive for a while it will automatically "wake up" the next time you call it.